# Is there a way to get pdf documents digitally signed in Oracle Integration Cloud Service or Oracle Visual Builder?

Tags: soa, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-soa, oracle-service-cloud, oracle-integration-cloud

I am quite new to this technology and the options I have explored is :

--> **Using native JavaScript to digitally sign the documents** : Since Oracle Integration Cloud Service supports uploading of JavaScript files only I have tried to use JavaScript and WebCrypto API but most of the functions have been deprecated.

--> **Using Adobe sign Adapter** : That just takes to the paid version which I do not want

The solutions which came to my mind and I cannot seem to find a path is :

--> **Tried using Java** : I cannot upload Java files in Oracle Integration Cloud Service. Or if there is a solution please do help me out.

--> **Tried to use Python** : Is there anyway I can connect to a Python Webserver and get things done in Oracle Integration Cloud Service?

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!!!